# connecting to an IP address instead of localhost?

Tags: c++, gcc, binding, client-server, winsock

this is my second go at this, I've written a server application as below which outputs whatever the client sends. I have one server.exe version where it listens to anything using `INADDR_ANY`, Having done that I can use my client and connect to the server if I specify the client connect to localhost (Which all works fine).

but if I use my own IP address instead of localhost for the client, I cannot connect to the server?. Shouldn't I be able to connect to the server this way?.

I used another server.exe which was hard-coded to use my IP address without having `INADDR_ANY` but it wasn't able to `bind()` or `listen()` to incoming connections. I'm confused as to how to proceed.

(I'm running the server and client on the same machine, is that an issue?)

server

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
using namespace std;

#define PORT 3490
#define IP "118.93.0.164"
#define BACKLOG 10

const int winsockversion = 2;

int main(void){
    WSADATA wsadata;
    if ( (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(winsockversion,0),&wsadata)) == 0){
        cout<<"-WSAStartup Initialized." << endl;

        struct sockaddr_in serv;
        memset(&serv,0,sizeof serv);
        serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        serv.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);//INADDR_ANY;//inet_addr(IP);
        //---------------------------------------
        struct addrinfo serv_addrinfo;
        serv_addrinfo.ai_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addrinfo.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        serv_addrinfo.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        serv_addrinfo.ai_addrlen = sizeof(serv);
        serv_addrinfo.ai_addr = (sockaddr*)&serv;


        //---------------------------------------
        SOCKET serv_con;
        serv_con = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
        if (serv_con != INVALID_SOCKET){
            cout<<"-Server Socket created." << endl;
        }

        if (bind(serv_con,serv_addrinfo.ai_addr,serv_addrinfo.ai_addrlen) != -1){
            cout<<"-Binding Successful." << endl;
        }

        if( listen(serv_con,BACKLOG) != -1){
            cout<<"-Listening for incoming connections." << endl;
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        SOCKET recv_socket;
        struct sockaddr_in client_info;
        int client_info_size = sizeof(client_info);

        char *con_addr = inet_ntoa(client_info.sin_addr);




        recv_socket = accept(serv_con,(sockaddr*)&client_info,&client_info_size);

        if( recv_socket != INVALID_SOCKET ){
            cout<<"-Connection Established!. " << endl;
            cout<<"-Connected to: [" << con_addr << "] " << endl;
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
            char buffer[80];
            int bytes_in;
            while(true){

                bytes_in = recv(recv_socket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
                if ( bytes_in > 0 ){
                    cout<<"[" << con_addr << "]" << buffer << endl;
                }

                if (bytes_in == 0 ){
                    cout<<"[" << con_addr << "] has disconnected." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                if (bytes_in == -1 ){
                    cout<<"-Possible Abrupt disconnecton from [" << con_addr << "]" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            closesocket(recv_socket);
            closesocket(serv_con);

        }

    }else{
        cout<<"-WSAStartup Initialization failed." << endl;
    }

    if( WSACleanup()!= -1){
        cout<<"-WSACleanp Successful." << endl;
    }

    WSAGetLastError();


    return 0;
}
```

client

```
/*client*/
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
using namespace std;

#define PORT "3490"
#define SERVER "118.93.0.164" // and localhost 
const int winsockVersion = 2;


int main(void){

    WSADATA wsadata;
    if ( (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0),&wsadata)) == 0){
        cout<<"-WSAStartup Initialized." << endl;

        struct addrinfo hints, *res;
        int sockfd;

        memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

        if (getaddrinfo(SERVER,PORT,&hints,&res) != 0){
            cout<<"-getaddrinfo unsuccessful." << endl;
        }

        if ( (sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol)) == -1 ){
            cout<<"-Unable to create socket." << endl;
        }

        if ( (connect(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen)) != -1 ){
            cout<<"-Connection Established." << endl;
        }

        cout<<"-Client connecting to: " << res->ai_addr << endl;

        while(true){
            string text_buff;
            cout<<"Enter text: ";
            getline(cin,text_buff);
            if( (send(sockfd,text_buff.c_str(),text_buff.length()+1,0)) != -1 ){
                cout<<"-text_buff sent!." << endl;
            }

        }

    }else{
        cout<<"-WSAStartup Initialization failed." << endl;
        if(WSACleanup()!=0){
            cout<<"-WSACleanup Successful." << endl;
        }else{
            cout<<"-WSACleanup Failed." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: running the server and client on the same machine is definitely NOT an issue. I suspect the IP address you are using is not really the address your machine owns. does your server has public address? or private address? Are you sure you are giving the IP address reported by ipconfig command?

Comment: You are right its not my machines IP address it is the IP address provided by my ISP. I have multiple computers connected via wifi, I was trying to connect to my external IP (if that is the name given for the IP adddress given by my ISP?).

Comment: how do I connect to an ISP given IP address and resolve the local address the server is running on?. (sorry not familiar with the jargon as yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a router you will have to set up [Port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). It really depends on what kind of router you have, so you will have to look it up for your specific one.

You cannot bind to your ISP's IP address, since you do not own it (the router does). You have to `bind` to an IP address that your computer actually owns, which is found via `ipconfig /all` in windows. Then make sure to forward traffic in your router for your servers portnumber, to the *internal* ipaddress that your computer has.

Comment: @Default, Are there any guides or tutorials on this?, I want to be able to do automatically without having to do it manually. I've read about UPnP, are there any well known places where I can hit this up?. Any start position will be much appreciated.

Comment: guides or tutorials to what? For port forwarding? Or do you want to be able to write your server/client programs and automatically bind to the internet? Because to my knowledge that cannot be done, you have to tell your HW what to do when stuff happends. How should your router know if you have a server on computer A and not on computer B? what if both A and B have a server for port x? What should the router do then? This is why you have to do it manually.

Comment: You might be wondering how other programs do it. Well, they have a server that is listening on internet (either the server they are using is directly on internet [not behind router] or they have port forwarding). Then, to connect between computers they connect to this server which then "relays" the information between the two computers. But this isn't really related, just trivia.

Comment: @sil3nt: do you really see it or was that just a nice comment? :) If you do not understand it, I'll try to explain it further.

Comment: @Default, no I understand, I'm just wondering how I would go about setting up such a thing just for fun. what about Apache? lol.

Comment: Apache is the same thing if you keep it on a computer that is behind a router, you need to route the traffic to port 80 to your machine.

Answer (score 0):

you may try using cmd to ping to server IP from your client side to see whether it is a connection problem.

Furthermore, i think this

```
#define PORT "3490"
```

in client side is wrong since port should be an integer.

Comment: the client is using getaddrinfo and It requires this.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to connect back to the server, are you using localhost/127.0.0.1, or the IP address you're listening on?

It may be that trying to connect to 'localhost' attempts to use the loopback interface, which your program isn't listening on. I'm not 100% sure how it works in Windows.

Can I ask a more important question that may prompt you to change your design: why do you want to bind to a particular IP (and localhost)?

Comment: My aim is to write a simple client-server chat(well more of a send and print on screen kind still) program so far it works on my local network. What I want to do is Have someone else outside my network connect to my server application using my ISP assigned ip address. This is really all I want to do