# How to run a live server win winsock?

Tags: c++, tcp, winsock

So I want to run a live server on my pc to connect and get info from someone else. I thought I can let the other person connect to my ip address on a port that is not used. So for example if my hypothetical ip address is 214.231.34.12 and port 50000 and I open te connection and give this information to someone, they can connect to it and send me information through TCP.

I thought I could use this code:

```
// TCPClient.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
/*
Live Server on port 50000
*/
#include<io.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s, new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int c;
    char *message;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("214.231.34.12");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(50000);

    //Bind
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts("Bind done");

    //Listen to incoming connections
    listen(s, 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while ((new_socket = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");

        //Reply to the client
        message = "Hello Client , I have received your connection. But I have to go now, bye\n";
        send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0);
    }

    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

But it is failing at binding the connection. This whole TCP and winsocket stuff is totally new to me and I do not understand how I should approach this differently. I know this code is not receiving any information yet, it is just the connection that I try to get working at the moment. Is this not the right way to set this up?

The bind() fails with windows socket error 10049

Comment: Is this your code or did you take it from somewhere?

Comment: Is 214.231.34.12 the IP of your PC or your router, which does NAT? If you are behind a router with NAT, you need to configure port forwarding. Also, don't bind your socket to the IP, just use `INADDR_ANY`, this makes it easier if there is NAT involved or your IP changes. Also, test your program locally first.

Comment: continue reading your book about sockets. you'll reach http programming then maybe you'll be able to do so. don't mix between http and tcp-udp/ip.

Comment: Fails on the `bind`. You print out the error code from `bind`. Editing your post to add the error code returned may help us help you.

Comment: @Hayt No I took it from a tutorial and then changed localhost to the ipaddress

Karsten Koop: It is the ip from my router I guess because I got the ipaddress from my internet provider

I added the bind error to the question

Comment: If you want to learn sockets etc. I encourage you to code this from scratch or at least read about and understand each function you see there. Also you should learn network communication in general (how IP and TCP works). In network communication a lot can go wrong. It best helps to understand what you are doing so you can at least narrow down what goes wrong yourself. For us to ask you for all the things to analyze and then come up with a fix for you, would be far too much.

Comment: @Hayt thanks! Yes I read about it and I understand the code, I just don't understand network communication very well yet. I think I just found some kind of solution for myself I will post it as an answer, because I think it works..

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of obstacles for establish a TCP connection over internet:

1. internet itself: bad/unstable connection, dynamic ips, etc
2. ISP: maybe your ISP blocks some ports or ips
3. router: router firewall, NAT traversal problems, upnp, etc
4. OS: windows firewall, antivirus, port blocked/in use
5. YOUR APP: maybe a code mistake

Is a complete new world link to pcs over internet, the concept is the same, but implement it......

Comment: Thanks I will check those things. I do have a static ip and a good connection, and I opened port 5000 on the modem/router. But yes there could be more things wrong

Comment: i suggest: test your program inside your network, in that case your "server" ip must be something like 192.168.0.2. When it works, try router traversal, in that case your server ip must be 214.231.34.12 (or something like this) BUT BOTH PCS (server and client) must be inside your network. And when it works, try full internet connection (both pcs in differents networks)

Answer (score 0):

So it might be an answer, but maybe I have to use another port as datenwolf suggested.

I found that it is not possible to bind to my ISP's ipaddress. So I have forward the port I want to use and then connect to the ipaddress of my computer, as mentioned here:

[connecting to an IP address instead of localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263913/connecting-to-an-ip-address-instead-of-localhost)

I tried that, so I changed the ipaddress in code to:

```
//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.178.93");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(50000);
```

And then when I connect to 214.231.34.12 and port 50000 with telnet, the connection works! I just wonder if this is a valid result?

Comment: Wait a second: Did you actually try to bind to an address that's not the one of your computer? You can only bind to addresses the machine the program is running on actually has. Your ISP is probably assigning your router a public address, but within your network you're on a private address range and you can of course only bind to that. If that's the case then port-forwarding as you did is the *only* valid way to do this. In that case it's also advisable not to explicitly bind to a certain address, but just bind to 0.0.0.0 which is "all address of this this machine".

Comment: Yes, I did not know that it was not possible, but now I do thanks! The tutorial I followed only bonded to localhost and connected to website ip-addresses. But I am fairly new to this so I figured I had to bind the server to the same ip-address as the one I want the client to connect to. But I was wrong ;) Oh and thanks then yes it is better to bind to 0.0.0.0 !