# How to acces sql server database that is on my desktop computer over the internet?

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection-string

I have a SQL server database,and I want to access it via my application over other device,like my laptop.If I am at home,and I am connected to my WIFI,all I have to do is change my connection string to the ip address of my computer where the sql server is and it works.
Can I somehow manage to connect to that database when I am not on my wifi?When I am somewhere else?
I have a free dns,I tried entering it in the connection string,under data source,but it is not working..
The app I am developing is a wpf desktop application

EDIT: This can't be done as easily is I thought,so this question isn't helpfull.

Comment: You can try a VPN tool, set up a VPN at your home and connect to it from outside the network. Then the ip address connection you described should work.

Comment: If the app is just for yourself why not just use something like remote desktop to access your home computer remotely.  If the app is for a larger audience then you should probably host it somewhere other than your home network.

Comment: This isn't a simple application configuration issue. You are going to have to change configuration in your router (assuming you're allowed to; this might be limited in routers provided by some of larger web providers). If this is something you don't feel comfortable doing, I'd look for a remote place to host it.

Comment: ok guys,thank you.I thought I could do it easily..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions is very tricky, that is not simple that you think, here i answer a similar question for another stackoverflow member:

[How to run a live server win winsock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394034/how-to-run-a-live-server-win-winsock/39394321#39394321)

Maybe in the best and simple case, your router support virtual servers (and that router module works), you can setup a virtual server pointing to your private/internal sql service.

If you have a dynamic ip from your ISP, thats works meanwhile that ip is valid

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a secure corporate login?  If you have a FOB key, or something along those lines, you can definitely do it.  I used to do this all the time at my previous job.